# what's the difference between calling render and leaving the implicit render run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, renderer

I'm developing my api where I would like to have everything presented as Json.

In the controller I have:

```
 def index
    @items = Item.all
 end
```

which renders the following:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body></body></html>
```

which is strange, because I don't have any layout files, and that the request was for a json mime.

but if I just add a call to `render` with no parameters, suddenly the `jbuilder` templates are used.

```
 def index
    @items = Item.all
    render 
 end
```

I don't really understand why the implicit renderer only renders in HTML, while I have to call `render` with no params to get a json response.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain with what's provided here, but there is an understood format being passed.

So lets say your code looks like this (I need the controller):

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end
end
```

and your route looks like this

```
resources :items
```

What this really says is this:

```
resources :items, defaults: {format: 'html'}
```

So if nothing else is done, it will assume that you are looking for an html response.

Try this: 
    class ItemsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json
      def index
        @items = Item.all
      end
    end

Then in your views, create index.json.erb or:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def index
    render json: Item.all.to_json
  end
end
```